# Getting CodeIgniter to save the values after form submittal

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and I'm really having a hard time getting the form values to repopulate after submitting a form in a simple CRUD app (on both error and success).  I thought it may help if I post my code here and maybe someone can help out.

Here is from my controller:

```
function update($id){

        $seller = $this->seller_model->get_seller_byID($id)->row();
        $data['seller'] = $seller;

        $data['title'] = 'Update seller';
        $data['message'] = '';
        $data['action'] = site_url('seller/updateSeller');
        $data['link_back'] = anchor('seller/ManageSellers/','Back to list of sellers',array('class'=>'back'));

        $this->load->view('EditSeller', $data);
    }

    function updateSeller(){

        $data['title'] = 'Update seller';
        $data['action'] = site_url('seller/updateSeller');
        $data['link_back'] = anchor('seller/ManageSellers/','Back to list of sellers',array('class'=>'back'));

        $this->setValidation();

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
        $data['message'] = 'fail';
        }
        else
        {
            $id = $this->input->post('id');

            $seller = array('s_fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
                            's_lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
                            's_email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                            's_password' => $this->input->post('pword'));

            $this->seller_model->update_seller($id,$seller);

            $data['message'] = '<div class="success">update seller success</div>';
        }   
        $this->load->view('EditSeller', $data);
    }

    function setValidation()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pword', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('dealer', 'Dealer', 'required');
    }
```

and here is my view:

```
    <html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
        <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

        <?php echo $message; ?>

        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

    <div class="content">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $action; ?>">
        <div class="data">           

                <p><?php
                    if (isset($seller->s_id))
                    {
                        echo "Id: " . $seller->s_id;
                        echo form_hidden("id", isset($seller->s_id) ? $seller->s_id : '' );
                    }
                ?></p>

                <p>First Name: 
                    <?php 
                        $field = array(  'name' => 'fname', 
                                         'size' => 30, 
                                         'class'=>'input', 
                                         'value' => (isset($seller->s_fname) ? $seller->s_fname : '' ) );
                        echo form_input($field, set_value('fname')); 
                    ?>
                </p>

                <p>Last Name: 
                    <?php 
                        $field = array(  'name' => 'lname', 
                                         'size' => 40, 
                                         'class'=>'input', 
                                         'value' => (isset($seller->s_lname) ? $seller->s_lname : '' ) );
                        echo form_input($field, set_value('lname')); 
                    ?>
                </p>

                <p>Email: 
                    <?php 
                        $field = array(  'name' => 'email', 
                                         'size' => 60, 
                                         'class'=>'input', 
                                         'value' => (isset($seller->s_email) ? $seller->s_email : '' ) );
                        echo form_input($field, set_value('email')); 
                    ?>
                </p>

                <p>Password: 
                    <?php 
                        $field = array(  'name' => 'pword', 
                                         'size' => 20, 
                                         'class'=>'input', 
                                         'value' => (isset($seller->s_password) ? $seller->s_password : '' ) );
                        echo form_password($field, set_value('pword')); 
                    ?>
                </p>

                <p>Status: 
                    <select name="status">
                        <option value="1" <?php echo set_select('status', '1', TRUE); ?>>Verified</option>
                        <option value="2" <?php echo set_select('status', '2'); ?>>Not verified</option>
                    </select>
                </p>

                <p>Dealer:
                    <input type="radio" name="dealer" value="Y" <?php echo set_radio('dealer', '1', TRUE); ?>/> Yes
                <input type="radio" name="dealer" value="N" <?php echo set_radio('dealer', '2'); ?>/> No
                </p>

                <p><?php
                    if (isset($seller->s_startdate))
                    {
                        echo "Start Date: " . $seller->s_startdate;
                    }
                ?></p>

           <input type="submit" value="Save"/>

               <p><?php echo $link_back; ?></p>

        </div>
        </form>
        <br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If my validation is successful, it saves to the database properly, but on the page reload the text box is not populated.  When there is a validation error, the database does not get altered as expected, but the values are not staying in the form fields.

Comment: We're getting there.  For some reason the seller array is not properly rendering in the view.  The following line of code (<?php echo "First Name is " . $seller->s_fname; ?>) never renders anything after form submitting.  Even after the change above.

Comment: Hi Carl, did you see my answer? I think it could help..

Answer (score 2):

change

```
  $field = array(  'name' => 'fname', 
        'size' => 30, 
        'class'=>'input', 
        'value' => (isset($seller->s_fname) ? $seller->s_fname : '' ) );
  echo form_input($field, set_value('fname'));
```

to

```
  $field = array(  'name' => 'fname', 
        'size' => 30, 
        'class'=>'input', 
        'value' => set_value('s_fname', (isset($seller->s_fname) ? $seller->s_fname : '' )) );
  echo form_input($field);
```

(and do the same for all the other similar occurrences.

You can learn more about set_value and repopulating the form [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform).

Comment: No, still doesn't work.  Syntax error is gone, but it is still not holding the values.  It is still saving to the database properly.

Comment: ...hang on - are you trying to repopulate the form EVEN if it is sucessful? If so - form_Validation wont do that - because the form 'passed' the test. You need to just re-load the variables and send them in a $data variable to the view file

Comment: "...hang on - are you trying to repopulate the form EVEN if it is sucessful?"    Yes.  I'm trying to use the same form for success and failure.

Comment: Still something not right here.  I'm going to experiment more later.

Comment: if form_validaiton is successful - then at the very end of it redirect to update($id) - this will then re-show the page, but with the data filled in

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, when updateSeller() completes, you are not sending back the $data['seller'] information to the view.

Here's a re-worked updateSeller() function:

```
function updateSeller(){

    $data['title'] = 'Update seller';
    $data['action'] = site_url('seller/updateSeller');
    $data['link_back'] = anchor('seller/ManageSellers/','Back to list of sellers',array('class'=>'back'));
    $data['seller'] = array();

    $this->setValidation();

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $data['message'] = 'fail';
    }
    else
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');

        $seller = array('s_fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
                        's_lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
                        's_email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                        's_password' => $this->input->post('pword'));

        $data['seller'] = $seller; // send form data back to view

        $this->seller_model->update_seller($id,$seller);

        $data['message'] = '<div class="success">update seller success</div>';
    }   
    $this->load->view('EditSeller', $data);
}
```