# Efficient Form Validation in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, codeigniter, validation

Can I ask for an efficient way to validate a form using PHP in Codeigniter platform?

I am considering two ways so far but both have their own disadvantages.

- Form_validation of PHP (but it erases the contents of the form whenever a rule is not followed)
- JQuery Validation (however, my rules also involve database checks (e.g. if username in form already exists in the database) and I cannot find a way to do that using javascript.)

Comment: js is for client validation ,you should always validate at serverside.this question is too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the first one and solve the issue of retaining the value after validation with `set_value()`

Check [Getting CodeIgniter to save the values after form submittal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12540397/getting-codeigniter-to-save-the-values-after-form-submittal)

Answer (score 0):

1. To make form validation easy and simple, you can find many jquery tools / plugins.
2. For server-side validation, you can choose CI form validation.
3. You have two option to retain text box / textarea values while reloading form after   validation error.

   a) use set_value -But you have to pass all field even it has no rules
   b) use `$this->input->post('field_name')`  - similar to `$_POST`. So you can echo `$_POST` 
     in value section of field.
   for ex:

   ```
    $field = array(  'name' => 'field_name',           
       'class'=>'validation_class_if_required', 
       'value' => set_value('s_fname', (isset($seller->s_fname) ? $seller->s_fname :    '' )) // or 'value' => $this->input->post("field_name")
   );
   ```

   echo form_input($field);